# How to avoid moving the key with HashMap entry/or_insert idiom if the entry already exists?

Tags: rust

```
hash_map.entry(key).or_insert(value);
```

The `key` is moved, so I need to clone it if I'd like to use it again. If such entry already exists the clone will be immediately dropped. How can I avoid cloning in such case?